# Using method sort() for sorting symbols in element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an element `cinema` of array `arr` by symbols unicode (in the output it must been like "**aceinm**"). I know that in this case we need to use method `sort()`. But I do know how inject sort method for array element.

Please, help. Code below are not working.

> Error: arr[1].sort is not a function.

```
var arr = ["cinema"];

arr[1].sort();
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Call sort on the entire array, not on the first element. Why are you trying to sort an array with a single element?

Comment: How your `arr` should be after sorting?

Comment: No matter how you sort `["cinema"]`, the result will always be `["cinema"]`. Therefore, you can just not do anything at all.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu He/she wants to sort the string not array

Comment: `arr[1]` is a string, not an array.

Comment: `arra[1].sort()` is wrong

Comment: @Li357 correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sort your string, you can easily do this by splitting and joining the string.

```
"cinema".split ("").sort ().join ("")
// aceimn
```

Or, in your case:

```
arr[0] = arr [0].split ("").sort ().join ("")
// arr: ["aceimn"]
```

If you need to sort all strings in an array, use `map ()`.

```
arr = arr.map (itm => itm.split ("").sort ().join (""))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

That's the same what I want. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are referring `arr[1]` which is not available also you have to `split` in order to sort the letters.

```js
var arr = ["cinema"];
var sorted = arr[0].split('').sort();
console.log(sorted, sorted.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var arr = ["cinema"];

console.log(arr[0].split("").sort().join(""));
```

EDIT: I see the same solution has been proposed by several others. I'll expand a bit on it.

Since you want to sort by the letters in the word cinema, and cinema is at index 0, you get the string "cinema" by calling arr[0], and then split the string with the method .split(""). This turns the string into an array that you can .sort() in the way you attempted initially.

The error you got, "Error: arr[1].sort is not a function", tells you that .sort() is not a function of the string element. Once you've turned the string into an array (for example with .split()), the .sort() function becomes available.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!